# How to center form controls with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

What am I missing?
I can see the border of the container and it correctly shows the area that I have to work with.
However when I add the row (div) and offset(div) it is left justifying it.

```
<div id="page" class="container" style="border:solid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="firstName" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="lastName" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is. http://www.bootply.com/q65r9cWljQ

Comment: the label and controls appear (intact) left justified.  I want them centered.

Comment: Only for you, I try your code and its centered.

Comment: can you post a picture of how your code is rendering in the browser?

Comment: please send the picture? we will give good answers.!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think I know what you are meaning, but I'm not sure. Do you mean like this?

[image: Test from Bootply]

If so, the class for that is:

```
class="text-center"
```

So you can change your code to this:

```
<div id="page" class="container" style="border:solid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
            <input id="firstName" class="form-control text-center" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
            <input id="lastName" class="form-control text-center" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or you can add it to just the controls you want, for example just the input form controls.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap can provide a great mobile experience, but desktops can also benefit from its scaffolding capabilities.  So, when I develop forms I like to use the least amount of space possible.  With that in mind I have improved on Demonic Penguin's code and your, as well. Like so:

```
<div id="page" class="container" style="border:solid">
  <div class="row" style="padding-top: 12px;"></div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input id="firstName" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="First Name" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input id="lastName" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Last Name" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this one out as well.  I do like this one as well.  Nice and clean.

Answer (score 0):

You can also embellish your form by adding icons to the fields, like so:

```
<div id="page" class="container" style="border:solid">
  <div class="row" style="padding-top: 12px;"></div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon" id="firstName-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
          <input id="firstName" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="First Name" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon" id="lastName-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
          <input id="lastName" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Last Name" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For this implementation, you must add a FontAwesome CSS reference link to your page(s) that you can get from here: https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/fontawesome/